# Python String Remove brackets Time Complexity

Tags: python, string, char

Suppose I wanna remove brackets from a string.

```
string="abc(d))qd()"
for x in range(len(string)-1,-1,-1):
    if string[x] in ["(",")"]:
       string=string[:x]+string[x+1:]
return string
```

if I iterate through the string from end and slice out  the specific index each time, it will take O(n) time for each slicing (I suppose, couldn't find the time complexity of string slicing). which pushes the total time complexity to O(n^2). And Space is O(1) I guess.

But if I convert my string to List using `stringList=list(givenString)` and instead of poping the element at specific index, I make that char at that index blank i.e. `stringList[n]=""` it only takes O(1) time. And latter I can iter through the list to join or use `"".join(stringList)`. This keeps my time to O(n) but space is also O(n).

```
lis=list(string)
for x in range(len(lis)):
        if string[x] in ["(",")"]:
           lis[x]=""
return "".join(lis)
```

Is there any better way?

**EDIT**
I asked this question in reference of this question on [leetcode 1249](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/submissions/) so I can't just remove all the Brackets from the string. That's why I didn't use replace.

I solved it like this

```
class Solution:
    def minRemoveToMakeValid(self, s: str) -> str:
        openBra=[]
        closeBra=[]
        for x in range(len(s)):
            if s[x] in ["(",")"]:
                if s[x]==")":
                    if len(openBra)==0:
                        closeBra.append(x)
                    else:
                        openBra.pop()
                else:
                    openBra.append(x)
        bras=set(openBra+closeBra)
        print(bras)
        ret=""
        for x in range(len(s)):
            if x not in bras:
                ret+=s[x]
        return ret
```

I was wondering if I could change the string s in place without driving the time or space complexity up.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your question completely, but you cannot `pop()` from a string in Python.

Comment: Strings are immutable; any viable solution is going to be at least O(n) with respect to space because you need to construct a new string, and unless you have some other index, it's also going to be at least O(n) wrt time because you need to iterate over the whole string to find the brackets.  Just use `str.replace` IMO.

Comment: "Remove Nth Chars" and "remove brackets" are different things. Please make up your mind and show an example.

Comment: I have updated the question and I want it to be removing brackets only.

Comment: I'd say that that LeetCode extension is rather a different question and would better be posted as such.

Comment: Can you guys please confirm, that string slicing and concatenation is indeed O(n) operations indeed.

Comment: @ShashwataSaha Yeah yeah, you're right about everything except the O(1) space usage for the first one (it's O(n)).

Comment: There's no way to "change string s in place" because strings are immutable.  You can only replace it with a brand new string.

Comment: @MarkRansom There is a way (with `id` and `ctypes`), and I'm actually curious whether it'll work for the LeetCode judge. Might try it later.

Comment: @KellyBundy in C or C++ they'd call that "undefined behavior".  Not sure what they'd call it in Python, but it can't be good.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah yeah, no good, and I wouldn't normally do it, but at LeetCode I don't care what it breaks (shouldn't be able to anyway) and the judge's acceptance is a nice goal for this. Haven't tried it yet, if I do it at all then I want it to actually be O(n) time and O(1) extra space, so no extra lists/set like in the OP's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out for long strings like `"abc(d))qd()" * 10**5`, `str.translate` is even faster than the `str.replace`s after all:

```
132.0 ms  listy
  8.5 ms  replaces
  2.0 ms  translate
  2.1 ms  translate2
 82.0 ms  re_sub
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLRioMwEHzPVyyBkkREzpbCUfBLSpFYk17uTPRihPbrvWiibY/SgGBmZ2ZHd7ub@2rN7rOz4yhtq8EpLZQDpbvWunhD8WYFQr2zylwKzKszrRn7rSnDCNVCQqN6d6Ohzg4I/PFQMcELOoOytXAFZcBycxG0EYZ6DouS6SgJQXC8nibiEVOcYoZPd0ow9/UC4xm0wg3WAMbZd6uCY4hlRdfws@ifk0V6wLLIoYSSFAhhd4AFIFg5n7hvuBPvvJ5ImeY/YkYomZ38Qxlh/w230TEFx6tGFO@k75vO@vXTy36oXoa1IptK5EjZKbovM0JyMOceijDQdP2B6T3uw@s2jW3QNFc5jWvWh26dt3RULhHYsj@QFJB/JMl@VpX3bdjFmK/MpuN8rrCUtOG6qvkBVvcUzKArYYucrfwQgGz2WS5B90BgA9RBArnYeYHMytJwLcqSPeRlaBz/AA)):

```
from timeit import timeit
import re

string="abc(d))qd()"

def listy(string):
    lis=list(string)
    for x in range(len(lis)):
        if string[x] in ["(",")"]:
           lis[x]=""
    return "".join(lis)

def replaces(string):
    return string.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')

def translate(string):
    return string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '()'))

def translate2(string, table=str.maketrans('', '', '()')):
    return string.translate(table)

def re_sub(string):
    return re.sub('[()]', '', string)

funcs = listy, replaces, translate, translate2, re_sub
for f in funcs:
    print(f(string))

string *= 10**5
for _ in range(3):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(string), number=1)
        print('%5.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3), f.__name__)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis of the two proposed solutions looks correct on the surface, but it's not using the built-in capabilities of Python in the most efficient way.  I'd just do:

```
return string.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
```

Each of the `replace` calls will be O(n).

Comment: Their "Space is O(1)" isn't right, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy each replacement of `string` will cause the old value to be reclaimed, so arguing about the space requirement seems pointless.

Comment: And I'd mention that this is a much faster O(n), 
at least for long strings I wouldn't be surprised about several orders of magnitude. Maybe clear to you and me, but beginners might otherwise not realize it and think they're about equally fast.

Comment: @KellyBundy that's the whole problem with big-O analysis, it doesn't tell you everything you need to know about timing in real world problems.

Comment: Well, *after* the replacement it's about the same amount of space, but *during* the replacement it's about three times as much.

Comment: I asked this question in reference of this question on [leetcode 1249](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/submissions/) so I can't just remove all the Brackets from the string. That's why I didn't use replace.

Comment: Posted a benchmark now, am surprised by the results. Other kinds of single-character searches are usually incredibly fast, and it has less than twice as much to scan than str.translate does, but it ends up over four times slower...